# Database evolutions not working in Play framework and I'm getting following exception

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, sbt, slick

I am using following line to run evolution scripts placed in `conf/evolutions/default/1.sql`

```
libraryDependencies += evolutions
```

And I'm getting unexpected exception

```
CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for play.api.db.DBApi was bound.
  while locating play.api.db.DBApi
    for parameter 3 at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider.<init>(EvolutionsModule.scala:45)
  at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsModule.bindings(EvolutionsModule.scala:22):
Binding(class play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions to ProviderConstructionTarget(class play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider) eagerly) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)

2) No implementation for play.api.db.DBApi was bound.
  while locating play.api.db.DBApi
    for parameter 0 at play.api.db.evolutions.DefaultEvolutionsApi.<init>(EvolutionsApi.scala:71)
  at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsModule.bindings(EvolutionsModule.scala:21):
Binding(interface play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsApi to ConstructionTarget(class play.api.db.evolutions.DefaultEvolutionsApi)) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)

2 errors
```

I'm using Scala version 2.11.7 with Slick 3.0.3 and Postgresql database. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I've also tried adding `db.default.driver` and `db.default.url` attribute in `conf/application.conf` file. That didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guice is failing because it is unable to create a database connection using the given configuration.

Ensure your configuration is correct and is pointing to correct db.

I am using `play-slick` with the following configuration and it works well for me.

build.sbt

```
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "2.0.0"
```

application.conf

```
slick.dbs.default.driver="slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url="jdbc:postgresql:dasldaljdlajdja"
slick.dbs.default.db.user=sasdas
slick.dbs.default.db.password="adasdasdas"
```

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: play.api.Logger$.init(Ljava/io/File;Lscala/Enumeration$Value;)V

After these configurations I'm getting this error. What I guess there came some dependency issue I've to resolve now. Matching my versions now.

Comment: @FahadSiddiqui ... its asking play.api.Logger ... its not the conf problem

Comment: play.api.Logger problem wasn't before making this change. so definitely it looks like a dependency incompatibility